# Replacing multiple values from a column in a dataframe based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

a newbie here. I have a dataframe `genes` which contains two columns: `Index` and `Name` such as:

`Index          Name 
 1              A
 2              B
 3              C
 4              D`

Another dataframe `similarity` contains 6-7 columns one of which is `Members` which includes different `Index` values separated by a space such as:

`Members
 1 3 5 7
 3 7
 6 9 2`

What I am trying to do is to replace the indices to `Names` by matching the `index` column from the dataframe `genes`. If the index is not found on `genes`, I simply want to put `NA` in its position.

So, based the example, my desired output is:

`Members
 A C NA NA
 C NA
 NA NA B`.

Comment: I apologize. I will try to do that next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We may do this with `chartr` and `gsub`

```
df2$Members <- gsub("\\d+", "NA", chartr(paste(df1$Index, collapse=""), 
                   paste(df1$Name, collapse=""), df2$Members))

df2
#    Members
#1 A C NA NA
#2      C NA
#3   NA NA B
```

---

Or another approach is to `split` the 'Members' column and then do the match based on the key/value pair from the first dataset ('df1')

```
df2$Members <- sapply(strsplit(df2$Members, "\\s+"), function(x) 
                  paste(setNames(df1$Name, df1$Index)[x], collapse=" "))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Index = 1:4, Name = c("A", "B", "C", "D")), .Names = c("Index", 
"Name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df2 <-structure(list(Members = c("1 3 5 7", "3 7", "6 9 2")),
  .Names = "Members", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for replying. I tried both your solutions. While using the first one in my full data, I get the following error:
`Error in chartr(paste(df1$Index, collapse = ""), paste(df1$Name, collapse = ""),  : 
  'old' is longer than 'new' `.

However, using the second approach I ran to this error:

`Error in strsplit(df2$Members, "\\s+") : non-character argument `. So, I separated the `Members` column from the dataframe and read it `as.character'. Now it's working. 

Cam you shed some light regarding why I am getting these errors?

Comment: @RasifAjwad  Regarding the first error, I was only using your example.  If you have used the 'data' I showed in my post, it would work.  Regardiing the second error, too, it works on my data because my 'Members' is `character` class and not `factor`.  Please change the code to `strsplit(as.character(df2$Members), "\\s+")`  The reason is that `strsplit` dont have an option to take a `factor` column

Comment: Yeah I fixed it already. But still confused about why the first solution isn't working. Will let you know if I am able to fix this. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RasifAjwad  Can you try by `as.character(df1$Index)` in that solution?  Do you have only single character strings as you described in the example?